# PHP - Trouble with Brakeing from a loop

Tags: php, loops

Question First: Am i going about this the wrong way?

I had trouble braking from my for each with a conditional if inside. I wrote this just to save CPU Time yet i could not brake from my foreach.

I am trying to comply with with Active Directory strict password enforcement and i don't believe in having maximum length passwords. As i have found some websites have Maximum length requirements.

```
foreach(count_chars($new_password, 1) as $key => $value){//Strength Test Results can be derived from $value
if(!ctype_upper(chr($key))){$check_upper=1;}//if Upper-case
if(!ctype_lower(chr($key))){$check_lower=1;}//if Lower-case
if(!ctype_digit(chr($key))){$check_digit=1;}//if Numeric
if(!ctype_punct(chr($key))){$check_punct=1;}//if Symbol
if($check_upper + $check_lower + $check_digit + $check_punct>= 3){
    break; 
    }//Save us from checking the entire string 
}
```

Comment: `break` not `brake`

Comment: you hit the wrong pedal your code car is going to crash and kill you.

Comment: Ah i retyped it in there without checking my spelling my bad.

Comment: So does your code work with the correct spelling?

Comment: Im going to have to say yes. I really have to focuses on one thing rather then many. I also updated PHP and ISS and Fast CGI and restarted my server and broke my code in another area all at the same time. Its properly why i make a few mistakes at least its all in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the wrong keyword! It should mean `break`

```
foreach(count_chars($new_password, 1) as $key => $value){//Strength Test Results can be derived from $value
if(!ctype_upper(chr($key))){$check_upper=1;}//if Upper-case
if(!ctype_lower(chr($key))){$check_lower=1;}//if Lower-case
if(!ctype_digit(chr($key))){$check_digit=1;}//if Numeric
if(!ctype_punct(chr($key))){$check_punct=1;}//if Symbol
if($check_upper + $check_lower + $check_digit + $check_punct>= 3){
    break; 
    }//Save us from checking the entire string 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well that's simple: `break`

Brake is what a car does.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php